# How to set AVAudioUnitEQ values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, avfoundation

In my code I have a reverb, echo, and pitch node that can be connected and successfully applied during playback of audio. However, I cannot get the EQ node to work. This is the section for the eq node (I am testing with the lower limit case but it does not filter the audio at all).

```
    let eqNode = AVAudioUnitEQ.init(numberOfBands: 1)
    if low {
            eqNode.bands[0].filterType = .LowPass
            eqNode.bands[0].frequency = 20
    }
    audioEngine.attachNode(eqNode)
```

The nodes are connected later in the code and all other nodes work. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioUnitEQ_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioUnitEQ/bands) provides an initialization method with only one parameter and a way to return an array of filter parameters but the array seems to be read-only so I'm not sure if the above code is actually changing the parameters. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, you need to set the bypass property. Not sure about AVAudioEngine, but using Audio Unit component services, this property defaulted to Active, meaning the effect was bypassed, so try setting bypass to NO. Also reading the docs, i believe you need to query the bands array for an instance of  AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters and set the parameters of the returns instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add: eqNode.bands[0].bypass = false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).